# file not found error while trying to move hadoop 2.6

Tags: hadoop

I tried to  install hadoop using the below link.
"http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php"

I was moving the files to /usr/local/hadoop.But i got the following error.

**hduser@vijaicricket-Lenovo-G50-70:~$ ~/hadoop-2.6.0$ sudo mv * /usr/local/hadoop**

**-bash: /home/hduser/hadoop-2.6.0$: No such file or directory**

Answer (score 0):

Where did you extract the hadoop tar file? As looking at the error from shell looks like " /home/hduser/hadoop-2.6.0" directory doesnt exist. Also make sure the valid permission user has.

Comment: /home/hduser/hadoop-2.6.0 directory is there. I do have permissions.But still getting the same error message

Comment: Does "/usr/local/hadoop" exist and permission ?